# React component life cycle methods don't work

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, jsx

I'm developing a React app using webpack and webpack-dev-server for development. However, all component life cycle methods (componentDidMount, componentWillMount etc.) other than getInitialState and render just don't work, while the components are rendered normally.

Example code:
https://gist.github.com/ryanaleksander/187308447d7665fd18aa1e6b8c5b656c

Comment: Seems you aren't making changes in your render method after receive ajax's response. What's the expected behaviour?

Comment: @JanCássio I'm expecting console.log inside componentDidMount() to actually print out something, but it doesn't

Comment: Try to replace `<App />` by `<h1>Hello World</h1>` at ReactDOM.render and see what's happening. Check your DOM and ensure you have an element with property id = 'app'.

Comment: @JanCássio A "big hello" world appears on the page

Comment: Cool! So, are you able to see `App` component at index with console.log(App)?

Comment: @JanCássio It's working now for reason unknown. Weird....

Comment: That's good, nice one!